# Min value with GROUP BY in Power BI Desktop

Tags: group-by, calculated-columns, powerbi, dax

```
id  datetime             new_column           datetime_rankx
1   12.01.2015 18:10:10  12.01.2015 18:10:10  1
2   03.12.2014 14:44:57  03.12.2014 14:44:57  1
2   21.11.2015 11:11:11  03.12.2014 14:44:57  2
3   01.01.2011 12:12:12  01.01.2011 12:12:12  1
3   02.02.2012 13:13:13  01.01.2011 12:12:12  2
3   03.03.2013 14:14:14  01.01.2011 12:12:12  3
```

I want to make new column, which will have minimum datetime value for each row in group by id.

How could I do it in Power BI desktop using DAX query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this expression:

```
NewColumn =
  CALCULATE(
    MIN(
      Table[datetime]),
      FILTER(Table,Table[id]=EARLIER(Table[id])
   )
  )
```

In Power BI using a table with your data it will produce this:

[image]

---

**UPDATE:** Explanation and `EARLIER` function usage.

Basically, `EARLIER` function will give you access to values of different row context.

When you use `CALCULATE` function it creates a row context of the whole table,  theoretically it iterates over every table row. The same happens when you use `FILTER` function it will iterate on the whole table and evaluate every row against the filter condition.

So far we have two row contexts, the row context created by `CALCULATE` and the row context created by `FILTER`. Note `FILTER` use the `EARLIER` to get access to the CALCULATE's row context. Having said that, in our case for every row in the outer (CALCULATE's row context) the `FILTER` returns a set of rows that correspond to the current `id` in the outer context.

If you have a programming background it could give you some sense. It is similar to a nested loop.

Hope this Python code points the main idea behind this:

```
outer_context = ['row1','row2','row3','row4']
inner_context = ['row1','row2','row3','row4'] 

for outer_row in outer_context:
    for inner_row in inner_context:
        if inner_row == outer_row: #this line is what the FILTER and EARLIER do

            #Calculate the min datetime using the filtered rows
            ...
            ...
```

---

**UPDATE 2:** Adding a ranking column.

To get the desired rank you can use this expression:

```
RankColumn = 
  RANKX(
    CALCULATETABLE(Table,ALLEXCEPT(Table,Table[id]))
    ,Table[datetime]
    ,Hoja1[datetime]
    ,1
 )
```

This is the table with the rank column:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! It really helps me. Can you explain what a function EARLIER does? Why does it fixed id?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКондратенко, check my update, hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it seems. When a calculation for the fourth row(id = 3), for example, EARLIER return column where id = 3?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКондратенко, Exactly, EARLIER allows filter the rows that correspond to id=3 and calculate the MIN only using those rows not the whole table.

Comment: And it means that I can change MIN to RANKX for example? Check my question update please.

Comment: I'm sorry, what are Hoja1 and 1 columns?

Comment: New = RANKX(FILTER('Table';[id] = EARLIER([id])); 'Table'[datetime]; )     
                                   New = RANKX(FILTER('Table';[id] = EARLIER([id])); 'Table'[datetime]; 1)
I've looked this. First case working, but second not

Comment: @ЕвгенийКондратенко, replace `Hoja1` by the name of your table.

Comment: How about if I want to compute average per id? Can I just change MIN to AVERAGE?

Comment: @bangbang, yes, why not?